# An FTP client that automatically detects and converts proper newlines?

Tags: ftp, text

If I am mistaken if this is already the case I apologize. I do most of my work on a Linux system and use Filezilla to often upload my work, unfortunately I sometimes open  a few files on my Windows PC when that is available and it messes up newlines completely. When I reopen them after being saved in Windows it becomes a garbled mess with no newlines.

Is there a plugin or option for Filezilla or a client you know of that will detect and take care of saving newlines automatically? It would save a lot of worry from having to dos2unix and unix2dos ALL the time.. and forgetting giving me consequences etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your [transfer type](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Data_Type) to Auto or ASCII and newline translation should be automatic.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I assumed not because this one time I tried on Windows using an online ftp (net2ftp), that possibly doubled the issues removing all the newlines hense my confusion.